# Error AADSTS700027 in PowerShell script using certificate to access Microsoft Graph API

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, certificate, microsoft-graph-api, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to make a powershell batch that changes users' MFA phonenumbers using GraphAPI.
I've went over some greatly helpful websites, and got to the script below. However I got stuck with the error AADSTS700027 : invalid signature and cannot fix over it. I've checked my azure portal for the Application and Certificates but they all seem to be fine.

```
$TenantName = "<MyTenant>.onmicrosoft.com"
$AppId = "<MyApplicationId>"
$Certificate = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\My\<MyThumbprint>
$Scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"

# Create base64 hash of certificate
$CertificateBase64Hash = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Certificate.GetCertHash())

# Create JWT timestamp for expiration
$StartDate = (Get-Date "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" ).ToUniversalTime()
$JWTExpirationTimeSpan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(2)).TotalSeconds
$JWTExpiration = [math]::Round($JWTExpirationTimeSpan,0)

# Create JWT validity start timestamp
$NotBeforeExpirationTimeSpan = (New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime())).TotalSeconds
$NotBefore = [math]::Round($NotBeforeExpirationTimeSpan,0)

# Create JWT header
$JWTHeader = @{
    alg = "RS256"
    typ = "JWT"
    # Use the CertificateBase64Hash and replace/strip to match web encoding of base64
    x5t = $CertificateBase64Hash -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='
}

# Create JWT payload
$JWTPayLoad = @{
    # What endpoint is allowed to use this JWT
    aud = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/token"

    # Expiration timestamp
    exp = $JWTExpiration

    # Issuer = your application
    iss = $AppId

    # JWT ID: random guid
    jti = [guid]::NewGuid()

    # Not to be used before
    nbf = $NotBefore

    # JWT Subject
    sub = $AppId
}

# Convert header and payload to base64
$JWTHeaderToByte = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($JWTHeader | ConvertTo-Json))
$EncodedHeader = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($JWTHeaderToByte)

$JWTPayLoadToByte =  [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($JWTPayload | ConvertTo-Json))
$EncodedPayload = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($JWTPayLoadToByte)

# Join header and Payload with "." to create a valid (unsigned) JWT
$JWT = $EncodedHeader + "." + $EncodedPayload

# Get the private key object of your certificate
$PrivateKey = $Certificate.PrivateKey

# Define RSA signature and hashing algorithm
$RSAPadding = [Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1
$HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA1

# Create a signature of the JWT
$Signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
    $PrivateKey.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($JWT),$HashAlgorithm,$RSAPadding)
) -replace '\+','-' -replace '/','_' -replace '='

# Join the signature to the JWT with "."
$JWT = $JWT + "." + $Signature

# Create a hash with body parameters
$Body = @{
    client_id = $AppId
    client_assertion = $JWT
    client_assertion_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"
    scope = $Scope
    grant_type = "client_credentials"

}

$Url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Use the self-generated JWT as Authorization
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $JWT"
}

# Splat the parameters for Invoke-Restmethod for cleaner code
$PostSplat = @{
    ContentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    Method = 'POST'
    Body = $Body
    Uri = $Url
    Headers = $Header
}

$Request = Invoke-RestMethod @PostSplat

# Create header
$Header = @{
    Authorization = "$($Request.token_type) $($Request.access_token)"
}

$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<MyUserObjectId>/authentication/phoneMethods"

$UserMFAPhoneNumber = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers $Header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
```

Here is the actual error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid s
ignature. [Reason - The provided signature value did not match the expected signature value., Thumbprint of key used by
 client: '<MyThumbPrint>', Found key 'Start=08/06/2020 15:23:55, End=08/06/2021 15:43:55', Pl
ease visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '<MyApplicationId>'. Review the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments to determine the
 corresponding service endpoint and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs
=http to build a query request URL, such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<MyApplicationId>']\r\nTrace ID: bdad204f-271a-40b0-ab3e-0bae5306c700\r\nCorrelation ID: 54edfc93-29fb-4c1b-ae12-40e79d3caa08\r\
nTimestamp: 2020-08-06 16:36:09Z","error_codes":[700027],"timestamp":"2020-08-06 16:36:09Z","trace_id":"bdad204f-271a-4
0b0-ab3e-0bae5306c700","correlation_id":"54edfc93-29fb-4c1b-ae12-40e79d3caa08","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonli
ne.com/error?code=700027"}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed that my Hash Algorithm wasn't aligned, and renewed my certificate for sha256RSA, and set `$HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256`. Now, I am getting the "Invalid algorithm" error. Both SHA1 and SHA256 aren't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your certificate is using sha256RSA you need to use the RSACertificateExtensions so if you change the following lines in you code that should work (well it does for me)

```
# Get the private key object of your certificate
$PrivateKey = ([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($Certificate))

# Define RSA signature and hashing algorithm
$RSAPadding = [Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1
$HashAlgorithm = [Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256
```

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I tried it out, but am still getting the "invalid algorithm" error. Also, it seems that this script uses the pfx file and the password. Is there no way to get around this? It goes directly against company security policies.

Comment: It should work the same from the cert store how did you generate the cert ?

Comment: `$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -HashAlgorithm sha256 -Subject "CN=MFAreset" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyLength 2048 -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature` Here is the code I used to create my certificate.

Comment: Okay I edit my answer because your certificate is sha256RSA you need to use the RSACertificateExtensions and also change the HashAlgorithm in your script

Comment: The edited answer worked and I got access to the API. Unfortunately, the API itself  had not yet supported application IDs so I couldn't really use it, however your answer was effective and very helpful. I've accepted the answer. Thank you for your kind assistance.